# What could be causing A ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, excel, numpy

I'm not sure how to fix this. My goal is to create an excel sheet, but I can't figure out what is causing the Value error.

```
def write_Excel():
            listofEncodedFilesNames = list(dictofEncodedFiles.keys())
            filename = np.array(listofEncodedFilesNames)
            RegID = np.array(listofRegisteredDocuments)
            RegIDList = np.concatenate((filename,RegID))
            print(RegIDList)
            
            #Create Workbook
            wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Uploaded RegisterID.xlsx')
            #add sheet is used to create shee
            sheet = wb.add_worksheet()
            row =1
            column = 1
            sheet.write('A1','Filename')
            sheet.write('B1','Registered ID')
            for filename, RegID in zip(RegIDList):  
                sheet.write(row, column, filename)
                sheet.write(row, column, RegID)                    
                column +=1
            wb.save() 
            wb.close()
            print(1/0)
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: Could you please add the traceback you get when you run the code? We can't tell much from this without knowing what line the error occurred

Comment: Although an answer is below, @Anonymous4045 is correct that some guesswork is required if you don't provide a stacktrace. When asking a question about errors, describe the problem in a short title, don't put the error there, but instead provide a copy of the full stacktrace in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
for filename, RegID in zip(RegIDList):
```

Compare this:

```
for a, b in zip([1]):
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

The same happens in your code - `RegIDList` is a list of single elements, with its `zip()` yielding 1-tuples, but you're trying to somehow spread that 1-tuple over two variables `filename` and `RegID`.

It looks like the elements in your list *are* tuples, but the result from the zip would still be 1-tuples with the first element being a 2-tuple, like this:

```
for a, b in zip([('x', 'abc')]):
    print(a)
```

Same problem - if you already have an iterable of tuples, why not just loop over that without the `zip()`:

```
            for filename, RegID in RegIDList:  
                sheet.write(row, column, filename)
                sheet.write(row, column, RegID)                    
                column +=1
```

Comment: Hello, I attempted to do that, but when I attempt to without the zip I receive this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Then it would appear that your tuples have more than 2 values - without code that people here can run to see what's going on, that's hard to say. You should probably try to inspect the value of `RegIDList` with a debugger before entering the loop, or if you don't have access to a debugger, `print` the list and see what the elements are. The number of variables in the `for` loop statement needs to match the number of elements of each tuple in the list (or `zip()` result) - if you don't need some of the values, you can have Python ignore them with an underscore, e.g. `filename, RegID, _`